# Identifying languages of individual words within list

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, language-detection

Suppose I have a list of words in different languages and I need to sort the words by language. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Currently I am using Python's [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/) which is very good at identifying individual words of unique character sets. For example '这是什么' has a > 0.99 probability of being Mandarin and 'תפוחים' a > 0.99 probability of being Hebrew, but struggles when given one word from different languages from the Latin alphabet. For example 'intro' is given a > 0.99 probability of being Italian and 'já' a > 0.99 probability of being Hungarian. I was thinking of somehow pooling the words together (as each language has multiple words) and 'sweaty intro' produces a > 0.99 probability of being English while 'ele já' produces a > 0.99 probability of being Portuguese.

```
testWords = ['这是什么', '这是什么', '王明是学生。', 'sweaty', 'intro', 'am', 'תפוח' ,'תפוחים', 'אני', 'criança', 'ele', 'já']
```

Comment: Without knowing the insides of the module, I'd suppose that you'll get better results the longer the sequences are. However, you won't get a 100% because some words are the same in multiple languages - think of `blond`, `experiment`, `minute`, `April`, `August` or `blitzkrieg` (ok ;-)). All of them have the same meaning in English and German for example. Besides these thoughts - what is your actual question?

Comment: Is there any possible way to distinguish between English and German in that example then?